# Error "get resource from application failed" in logcat of android 4.0.2

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

First of all My app runs smoothly on 4.2.2 without showing this error in logcat but in 4.0.2(all of my users are in 4.0.2) this shows and slows down my application.
I have used these libraries

> Acra-4.5.0, httpclient(of apache), httpcore, httpmime, Java-websocket-1.3.0

this error shows on every intent switch or action and bringing down performance. Also it happens only on 4.0.2 of android. All the textviews are working properly too. 
Any place where I can see the change log of sdk 15 to sdk 17?
[image]

Also it happens on the Looper class as I have debugged the app quite thoroughly. I am pretty stuck and cannot get out of it as I am pretty new in android. :( :(

Comment: which mobile you are using..?Can you try with other devices..?

Comment: Its a mobile specific issue, Thanks